# Cronjob can't execute notify-send

Tags: linux, bash, cron, notifications

I have the following file `~/.config/local_scripts/notifier.sh` with this content:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

notify-send -t 10000 "Cronjob" "Test succeeded"
```

This is in my crontab, if I execute `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * ~/.config/local_scripts/notifier.sh && echo "Succeeded" >> ~/test.txt
```

Here are the permissions:

[image]

Now I'm getting my `Succeeded` in my `text.txt` file but I'm not getting the notification. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cron jobs are intended to run "headless" -- it has no connection to your desktop environment.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much guys! I needed to export the dbus session as well. Finally I'm getting my notification! Thank you! You can mark the question as a duplicate.